# Can't connect to mysqldb in Django "ImportError: cannot import name 'CLIENT' from 'MySQLdb.constants' (unknown location)"

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x

I have been fought all day, but i fail. I have problem with connection to MYSQL database. I using Linux Debian and i try connect to local database, but something went wrong :/.

Bellow attached settings.py

```
# settings.py

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dbDjango',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': '*******',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
```

But, when i run server using

`python3.7 manage.py runserver` the program call back me error like this:

```
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 117, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 22, in <module>
    from MySQLdb.constants import CLIENT, FIELD_TYPE                # isort:skip
ImportError: cannot import name 'CLIENT' from 'MySQLdb.constants' (unknown location)
```

Mysql as service is runing:

```
ervice mysql status
● mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-10-03 00:14:56 CEST; 36min ago
```

I don't have any idea , what can make trouble :((
Thank's for an answer

Comment: Problem solved :). Enough use in MySql  SET GLOBAL time_zone="+2" ;